# NULL Id token returned from VerifyPassword Firebase .NET API

Tags: c#, firebase, .net-core, firebase-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I have webapi in .NET core using Firebase for Authentication. When I am trying to use VerifyPassword route as a part of Sign-in with email and password, I am getting NULL id-token and refreshtoken.

I have been passing returnSecureToken= token in the request. URL used for making request is (with correct _apiKey:

[image]

and the response I am getting is:

[image]

Can anyone please suggest me what I am might be missing?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)